# Is there a way to make the layout of a JPanel like a tree graph?

Tags: java, swing, tree, hierarchy

Hi guys i am trying to make a tree graph. I already made the nodes and the connection between them, by extending jFrame and @override the paintComponent from jpanel. Can i somehow change the Layout of the jPanel to be like tree graph? Any suggestions ? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: *"Is there a way to make the layout of a JPanel like a tree graph?"* Sure. Use a `TreeGraphLayout`.

Comment: really? I didnt know that jpanel had such Layout. Also i can not find it anywhere. :/

Comment: *"i can not find it anywhere"* That's because it's a custom layout manager that you need to code. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that layout you can use [abego TreeLayout](https://github.com/abego/treelayout)
and for the drawing that won't help you a lot , sorry .
and am sorry but a just a while i saw a question asking for a graphics issue with a tree that i was about to answer but i can't find it any more .

both of the questions are very relative so for either cases i think the problem is about getting the right location of the node you can get it using

```
Component.getLocation();
```

to get the location of the node relative to it's parent , so it best fit for the drawing lines between the nodes in your overridden `JPanel` and by using the

```
Component.getWidth();
```

and

```
Component.getWidth();
```

with the location method you can find the start point of the line-end start point(assuming you start the line with bottom right  ending at the top left).
.

Comment: Yes you are right, the tree is created correctly but with out the right possition of the nodes. I will try those methods you propose. Thank you very much for your time.